# Factorising $t ^6 − 10t ^4 + 31t ^2 − 30$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, cubics

Does anyone know how I can factorise $t ^6 − 10t ^4 + 31t ^2 − 30$? I can see the answer using WolframAlpha but I want to know how to do it by hand without guessing roots.

Comment: You should guess one root $r_1$ and then do divide the polynom by $(t-r_1)$

Comment: @Nehorai Thanks, I am wondering if there is a shortcut at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$t^6 - 10t^4 + 31t^2 - 30 = t^2(t^4 - 10t^2 + 25) + (6t^2 - 30)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I honestly don't see how you found this expression, or how it helps...

Comment: Hint #2:  Check for a common binomial factor.

Comment: Hint #3: $t^2-5$ is the key factor

Comment: Indeed, @z100!  =)

Comment: Fair enough, this expression makes the factor $t^2-5$ more clear. But I don't see how one is supposed to find the expression you give?

Comment: @Servaes : Experience, a lot of practices :-)

Comment: Hint #4: @Servaes, for equations in quadratic form, a quick attempt at factoring can be done by grouping and **completing the square**.  *Warning*: This does not always work for every equation in quadratic form, though.

Comment: Aha, I hadn't realised it was a square.

Comment: how did you spot it was a square?

Comment: @helppls,well $t^6 - 10t^4$ is almost a square, whence you can complete the square:

$$(t^6 - 10t^4 + 25t^2) - 25t^2 = {t^2}(t^2 - 5)^2 - 25t^2.$$

Now, all that remains to be done is to group the $-25t^2$ with $31t^2 - 30$.  =)

Answer (score 5):

Write the polynomial in terms of $X:=t^2$ as $X^3-10X^2+31X-30$. Its roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ can be found by the rational root test. The roots of $t^6-10t^4+31t^2-30$ are then $\pm\sqrt{\alpha}$, $\pm\sqrt{\beta}$ and $\pm\sqrt{\gamma}$.